# I'm creating a permit tracker list, I want an automated flow to populate a column with a number based on another columns permit choice

Tags: list, power-automate

Essentially all the permits will have specific days before to submit. I have a choice column which chooses what type of permit it is. I want to auto populate a column with how many days before the permit begins that the permit needs to be submitted based on the choice of what type of permit is chosen. There are a set amount of Permit types. As seen in the picture, there is a column where a choice is made for what type of permit, next column is the days before the permit is active the permit is due and the next column is the date the permit will be active.
[image: Screenshot of the list]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have another list which contains the correlation between **Permit Type** and **Days Before Works Starts Permit Date** - My example list here is called **Master List** and contains relation between **Priority** and **Days**. Replace **Priority** with **Permit Type** for your case.

[image]

The Power Automate flow will be something like this:

- Get newly created / updated item (Depends on your requirements)
- Get master list data, filter by item's field (In your case will be **Permit Type**. My eg is **Priority**)

Formula eg to be used in **Filter Query** field:
`Priority eq 'outputs('Get_newly_created_item')?['body/Priority/Value']'`

- Update item with value retrieved from master list data

Screenshot illustration:

[image]